# How do I return a class' enums from its own class in Java?

Tags: java, enums

I want to enforce enum implementation in Java but I found out that I couldn't do it.
So I decided to define an abstract function that returns the enums of subclasses. But don't know how to do it.

Here is the code:

EnumInterface

```
public interface EnumInterface 
{
    public String getString();
}
```

ParentClass

```
public abstract class ParentClass {
    public abstract Enum<?> getEnums();
}
```

ChildClass

```
public class ChildClass extends ParentClass{
    public enum EnumImplementation implements EnumInterface
    {
        FOO("foo"), 
        BAR("bar");

        String string;

        EnumImplementation(String field)
        {
            this.string = string;
        }

        @Override
        public String getString() {
            return string;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public Enum<?> getEnums() {
        return ?;
    }    
}
```

The code above doesn't work, I'm just trying to describe my problem.
I also want to enforce the enum return type to `EnumInterface` if possible.
If you know how to enforce specific enum implementation that would be better as I don't even have to define the function in `ParentClass`.

So, how do I return the enum so that I can just do this `instanceOfParentClass.getEnums().FOO`?

Comment: Why are you trying to do this/what are you trying to achieve? There is probably a better way...

Comment: I want to use them to map property names to database field

Comment: @TimB I want to use them to map class property names to database field names. I want force the developers to prepare an interface between them. Sometimes I do want to use the enums to define which attribute to show on the UI. Enums enable me to easily define which property to use and pass them to other classes, like this : `Class.Attribute.NAME`. Do you have any better solution?

Comment: See answer I just posted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about this:

```
public <T extends Enum<T> & EnumInterface> T[] getEnums() {
    return (T[])EnumImplementation.values();
}
```

Note the cast, which might result in a `ClassCastException`.
To prevent this you could pass the enum class or just return an array of `EnumInterface`:

```
public <T extends Enum<T> & EnumInterface> T[] getEnums(Class<T> enumType) 
public <T extends Enum<T> & EnumInterface> EnumInterface[] getEnums()
```

Note that this doesn't enable you to call the method like `getEnums().FOO`, but you could pass the class and the name, e.g.

```
public <T extends Enum<T> & EnumInterface> T[] getEnum(Class<T> enumType, String enumName) {
    return Enum.valueOf( enumType, enumName);
}
```

However, just as Tim B said, there might be a better option for what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: This won't let him do getEnums.FOO though.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, could you take a look at my comment to Tim in the main question. Do you have any better solution than this for my problem?

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

**EnumInterface**

```
public interface EnumInterface {
    public String getString();
}
```

**ParentClass**

```
public abstract class ParentClass<ENUM_TYPE extends Enum<ENUM_TYPE> & EnumInterface> {
    public abstract ENUM_TYPE getEnums();
}
```

**ChildClass**

```
public class ChildClass extends ParentClass<ChildClass.EnumImplementation> {
    public static enum EnumImplementation implements EnumInterface {
        FOO("foo"), 
        BAR("bar");

        String string;

        EnumImplementation(String field) {
            this.string = field;
        }

        @Override
        public String getString() {
            return string;
        }
    }

    public EnumImplementation getEnums() {
        return EnumImplementation.values()[0];
    }

    public static void test() {
        Object result = new ChildClass().getEnums().FOO;
    }
}
```

Note that `getEnums()` returns an enum value. It's not possible to return the enum container itself, but you can call other enum values from any value (f.e. `EnumImplementation.FOO.BAR.FOO`)

Answer (score 0):

In order to map property names to database field you can use the enum valueOf method.

You need to do the mapping in your class as you cannot pass a reference to the static enumeration:

http://www.tryjava8.com/app/snippets/52b86150e4b0f5090255bc45

```
 import java.util.*;
 public class Main{

     static enum TestE {
         FOO,
         BAR
     }

   static class TestC {
     TestE getEnum(String name) { 
       return TestE.valueOf(name);
     }
   }

   public static void main(String[] args){
     System.out.println(TestE.FOO);
     System.out.println(new TestC().getEnum("BAR"));
   }
 }
```